# Cannot setup the function with out parameter using lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda, moq

I've found loads of questions to the error message, but not one that matches my specific case.

I have a method with this signature in a cache implementation:

```
public bool TryGet(TKey key, out TValue returnVal, Func<TKey, TValue> externalFunc = null)
```

I have a class derived from that with TKey : CompositeKey and TValue : string.

I'm trying to mock it for unit testing like this:

```
_cacheMock
    .Setup(x => x.TryGet(It.IsAny<CompositeKey>(), out It.Ref<string>.IsAny, It.IsAny<Func<CompositeKey, string>>()))
    .Returns((CompositeKey key, out string s, Func<CompositeKey, string> fetchOne) => { s = ""; return true; });
```

I get a compilation error for the `.Returns` line:

> "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'bool' because it is not a
>   delegate type"

If I remove the "out" modifier it compiles OK - but of course doesn't match the signature of the call and I can't get the out value out.

Is there a way to fix the Returns() part of the statement without modifying the TryGet() method itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
//define the callback delegate
delegate void TryGetCallback(CompositeKey key, out string str, Func<CompositeKey, string> func);

mock.Setup(x => x.TryGet(
        It.IsAny<CompositeKey>(), 
        out It.Ref<string>.IsAny, 
        It.IsAny<Func<CompositeKey, string>>()))
    .Callback(new TryGetCallback((CompositeKey key, out string str, Func<CompositeKey, string>  func) => 
    { 
        str = "foo bar"; 
    }))
    .Returns(true);
```

with such a setup you could archive what you want

```
string actualValue;
bool result = mock.Object.TryGet(new CompositeKey(), out actualValue)
//actualValue = "foo bar", result = true
```

Comment: Thank you for providing an example built from my own code, and yes, it actually compiles and works correctly! Good stuff!